# okta infinite loop sign in

Tags: spring-boot, angular, auth, amazon-web-services, ec2

I have angular+springboot website. Its deployed on aws ec2. front and back on separate instances. Everything working fine except okta sirn in. Infinite sign in looks like this:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

On localhost everything working fine, but when its deployed i get infinite sign in. As you see i dont even get errors about okta. Also when i press login button I get 12 issues about cookies as you see:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Maybe this is the reason? How can i fix this? Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.